# Energy of Sagittarius A*'s Relativistic Jet

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes, explosions

As far as I have known, our center of the Milky Way, the supermassive black hole Sagittarius A*, weighing 4,000,000 times the mass of our sun, had erupted 3.5 million years ago, the explosion of relativistic jets so powerful that it had struck the Magellanic Stream 200,000 light years away.

However, I am unable to find any site that states the exact energy released from this event. Does anyone know the likely approximate values of how powerful the event was?